# Pentaho Logging specify Job or Trans for each line

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am running Pentaho Kettle 6.1 through a java application.  All of the Pentaho logs are directed through the java app and logged out into the same log file at the java level.

When a job starts or finishes the logs indicate which job is starting or finishing, but when the job is in the middle of running the log output only indicates the specific step it is on without any indication of which job or trans is executing.

This causes confusion and is difficult to follow when there is more than one job running simultaneously.  Does anyone know of a way to prepend the name of the job or trans to each log entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know, and I doubt there is for the simple reason that the same transformation/job may be split to run on more than one machine, by more that one user, and/or launched in parallel in different job hierarchies of callers.

The general answer is to log in a database (right-click any where, Parameters, Logging, define the logging table and what you want to log). All the logging will be copied to a table database together with a channel_id. This is a unique number that will be attributed to each "run" and link together all the logging information that comes from all the dependent job/transformations. You can then view this info with a `SELECT...WHERE channel_id=...`

However, you case seams to be simpler. Use the database logging with a log_intervale of, say, 2 seconds and `SELECT TRANSNAME/JOBNAME, LOG_FIELD FROM LOG_TABLE` continuously on your terminal.

You can also follow a specific job/transformation by logging in a specific table, but this means you know in advance which is the job/transformation to debug.